# PHP - check if object exists from a array of objects by comparing by all properties of needle

Tags: php

I have objects. One is needle which is simple object with several properties and another one is haystack which array of objects.

Here is needle

```
DeviceType Object
    (
        [idDeviceType] => 167
        [Name] => monirul
        [TargetURL] => www.google.com
        [idAccessPlan] => 1
    )
```

Here is haystack,

```
Array
(
    [0] => DeviceType Object
        (
            [idDeviceType] => 167
            [Name] => monirul
            [TargetURL] => www.google.com
            [idAccessPlan] => 1
        )

    [1] => DeviceType Object
        (
            [idDeviceType] => 168
            [Name] => monirul iPad
            [TargetURL] => www.yahoo.com
            [idAccessPlan] => 1
        )

    [2] => DeviceType Object
        (
            [idDeviceType] => 169
            [Name] => monirul phone
            [TargetURL] => www.bing.com
            [idAccessPlan] => 1
        )
)
```

Now i want to check if my needle exists in haystack. Not just by any specific property but also by whole object property(idDeviceType, Name, TargetURL, idAccessPlan). How can i achieve this efficiently? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of variations using `serialize`.  If you just want to know if needle is in haystack then this is simple:

```
$result = strpos(serialize($haystack), serialize($needle)) !== false;

var_dump($result); //gives true or false
```

Comment: your array_intersect_recursive function not talking any parameter. Could you check please?

Comment: I was making it too complicated.

Comment: AbraCadaver could you please take a look for this? http://pastebin.com/0qZxLxtd . This time object name is different. Thats the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
if (in_array($object, $array_of_objects)) { /* do stuff */ }
```

If you want to check if *the same instance* of the object exists in the array, add "true":

```
if (in_array($object, $array_of_objects, true)) { /* do stuff */ }
```